# Trying to stall main-thread while background worker displays a user-interactive form in C#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, semaphore, windowsformshost

I'm making(trying) to make a dialogue box similar to the openFileDialogue where the program flow of the Main Thread is stalled until the `OPF.ShowDialogue()` function stalls while running a separate thread.

I have a `OpenFileDialogue_Gui` class which uses a semaphore and a background worker.

The background worker is first launched to generate a separate form with the necessary user-interface

Then the semaphore stalls the main thread until the user clicks one of the buttons on the background thread's form.

Then it releases the semaphore and the result is sent back to the calling function.

Sounds nice in theory, but there's a problem. The background-worker is not displaying its form and it's not working.

Here's the code :

```
public class openfiledialogue_Gui
{
    Semaphore semStall = new Semaphore(0, 1);
    BackgroundWorker bck = new BackgroundWorker();

    public openfiledialogue_Gui()
    {
        bck.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bck.DoWork += Bck_DoWork;
        bck.RunWorkerCompleted += Bck_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    public enum enuResult { Ok, Cancel, _num };
    public enuResult ShowDialogue()
    {
        bck.RunWorkerAsync();
        semStall.WaitOne();
        return eResult;
    }

    enuResult eResult = enuResult.Cancel;

    void EventOk_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            eResult = enuResult.Ok;
            strFilename = "ok clicked";
            semStall.Release();
        }

    void EventCancel_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            eResult = enuResult.Cancel;
            strFilename = "cancel clicked";
            semStall.Release();
        }

    private void Bck_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e){semStall.Release();}

    private void Bck_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Form frmShow = new Form();
        Button btnOk = new Button();
        btnOk.Text = "ok";

        Button btnCancel = new Button();
        btnCancel.Text = "Cancel";

        btnOk.AutoSize
            = btnCancel.AutoSize
            = true;

        frmShow.Controls.Add(btnOk);
        frmShow.Controls.Add(btnCancel);

        frmShow.ControlBox = false;

        btnOk.Location = new Point(100, 25);
        btnCancel.Location = new Point(100, 75);

        btnCancel.Click += EventCancel_click;
        btnOk.Click += EventOk_click;
        frmShow.Show();

    }

    public string strFilename = "this is a test";
    public string Filename
    { 
    get { return strFilename; }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: I usually use the state object in the report progress for backgroundworker to send text to main thread. Then in main thread add your code to show form.

Comment: thanks, but what I'm trying to do is have the calling form stall(the same way the OpenFileDialogue native to C# does) while the backgroundworker shows the form.  unfortunately, everything is stalled right now.

Comment: You cannot do that!!! The background class is in a different thread from the form.  You have to create a Report Progress Event method in the form class and then from the Event open the dialog.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this code.  You ask about the deadlock you got from calling semStall.WaitOne().  That hangs the UI thread, preventing the RunWorkerCompleted event from ever getting activated.  But much more wrong than that.  You must call the form's ShowDialog() method instead, strictly on the main thread.

Comment: OK.  so the worker-thread cannot run a form.  but is there a way to create a form-show it-while stalling the main-thread until a user clicks 'ok' and have that form return a value in a way similar to OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() ?

Comment: You shouldn't 'stall' the main UI thread.  this is bad design.  The UI thread must always be 'free-flowing' to maintain user responsiveness.  BackgroundWorkers are just that, they work in the background, so that the main UI thread never blocks.  You need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to make a 'Modal Form'.

```
var form = new MyModalForm();
form.ShowDialog();
```

This will 'stall' the UI until you cancel (or otherwise close) the form.

Comment: wow!  That's what it is.  That's the magic word I was looking for trying to twist myself into a knot to make it work when there's the ShowDialog() native instruction all along.  thank you.